# Reading names of thousands of jpeg files as input in Spring Batch

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-batch, batch-processing

I am using Spring Batch and defining a job for my batch process but the problem is that i need to read names of 80.000 jpeg files from a specific directory as input , i want to read for example 1000 per chunk.
I also heard about Spring Integration for doing this but i dont know if this is right way or not.
Please guide me if i am taking right approach or not.

Thanks.

## UPDATE:

Should i fetch all files into a collection structure like List or something else when i want initialize my custom Item Reader? is it optimum?
I want to read items at once from database based on name of each file. how should i do this by a `JpaPagingItemReader` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That really depends on what you want to do with the JPEGs.  Based on your interest in chunking them at 1000 per chunk, there really isn't any reason to get Spring Integration involved unless you need it for some form of orchestration capabilities (run the job when files appear for example).

Just use an `ItemReader` and configure your step to chunk at 1000.  You could even partition them if they can be processed in parallel using out of the box components within Spring Batch.

Comment: I wanna read just name of every jpeg file as an input and find a record in database based on the name.

Comment: And i also want to keep track of read jpeg files and know which is read or not if job corrupted in midway.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Spring Integration `FileReadingMessageSource` really can be used for this task. The read file is as `payload` of emitted message . You can use `maxMessagesPerPoll = 1000` to get your maximum per one polling task.

If you really need to combine them to a single message, you would need an `aggregator`.

Sorry, I don't know Spring Batch so good to advice you something from that perspective.

Comment: `spring-batch-integration` provides job launching message handler and gateway which can be invoked from an integration flow.